# Codigo para tamaño de fuente

Tags: c#

Me pueden ayudar con un código? Estoy trabajando en una "Calculadora científica" agregue una TextBox la cual quiero que el tamaño de fuente se haga mas chica cuando escriba cierta cantidad de números, espero puedan ayudarme(estoy trabajando en c# Windows Forms)

---

aunque  tengo un nuevo problema tu código me funciona pero cuando compila la textBox se hace pequeña no sabes algún código para que tenga el mismo tamaño? yo tenia este pero no funciona: txtResultado.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(285, 80);

Comment: Hola @Nayeli Valle, no lo tomes a mal pero, tu pregunta no se adecua a las reglas del sitio, debes poner los avances de tu codigo, ya que asi sera mucho mas facil de ayudarte y detectar donde esta el error y/o complementarle alguna mejoria, te invito a que te des una pasadita por [https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour] aqui te enseñran como redactar una buena preguna

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que calcular el length de el textbox para saber cuántos dígitos tiene, entonces en el evento change de el textbox puedes hacer algo como esto:

Suponiendo que txtResultado es el nombre de tu textBox y que 10 es el número de caracteres máximos en el que el tamaño es 16

```
If (txtResultado.text.length >= 10){
   txtResultado.Font = new Font("Courier New", 12);
} else {
   txtResultado.Font = new Font("Courier New", 16);
}
```

Comment: No todas las preguntas pueden o deben responderse. Ahórrate un poco de frustración y evita responder a preguntas que solicitan opiniones en vez de realidades, o que no tratan sobre programación o desarrollo tal y como lo definimos en el centro de ayuda. Lee [answer] para más información.